# Open source for Android game development

Tags: android

Guys I am new to game development in Android. I need to refer to few good open sources for Android game development. Can someone provide me with good sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Android website, http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html

Web:
http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/12/15-nice-and-simple-open-source-android.html

Replica Island should get one started,
http://replicaisland.blogspot.com/
code:
http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/

and if you are writing Android games like replica island, one should watch,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic

and if interested  to know about Game design , one should read this book,
Beginning Android Games.
http://www.apress.com/9781430230427

libGDX:
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Answer (score 6):

Below is list of some good open sources games in Android

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications#Games

Answer (score 2):

Why people only refer replicaisland? There are still lots of game libraries available for Android... Like libgdx, jMonkeyEngine 3 (it supports OpenGL 2 and the current emulator supports OpenGL ES 1.x), Cocos2D and AndEngine...